# How to Integrating Apache Drill to Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, apache-drill, jupyter-lab

I would like to integrate Drill in jupyter Notebook. Any suggestion/help how this can be achieved?

I have come across a blog in mapr that uses magics, but i am getting an exception with Error code 500 with '%drill connect' command in jupyter notebook.

Here is the article https://mapr.com/blog/drilling-jupyter/
https://github.com/JohnOmernik/jupyter_drill

Answer (score 0):

If you were trying to connect to an *unsecured* Drill API then your description sounds exactly like the problem I hit.  I came up with a patch for the unsecured case and sent a [pull request upstream](https://github.com/JohnOmernik/jupyter_drill/pull/7).